# SQL Computation of Cosine Similarity

Tags: sql, cosine-similarity

Suppose you have a table in a database constructed as follows:

```
create table data (v int, base int, w_td float);
insert into data values (99,1,4);
insert into data values (99,2,3);
insert into data values (99,3,4);
insert into data values (1234,2,5);
insert into data values (1234,3,2);    
insert into data values (1234,4,3);
```

To be clear `select * from data` should output:

```
v   |base|w_td
--------------
99  |1   |4.0
99  |2   |3.0
99  |3   |4.0
1234|2   |5.0
1234|3   |2.0
1234|4   |3.0
```

Note that since the vectors are stored in a database, we need only store the non-zero entries.  In this example, we only have two vectors $v_{99} = (4,3,4,0)$ and $v_{1234} = (0,5,2,3)$ both in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

The cosine similarity of those vectors should be $\displaystyle \frac{23}{\sqrt{41 \cdot 38}} = 0.5826987807288609$.

**How do you compute the cosine similarity using nearly only `SQL`?**

I say nearly because you will need the `sqrt` function which is not always provided in basic `SQL` implementations, for example it is not in `sqlite3`!

Comment: You can actually use `sqrt` in sqlite3 by compiling and using math extension library. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416482/load-sqlite3-extension-in-python3-sqlite/54959853#54959853) for details.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
with norms as (
    select v,
        sum(w_td * w_td) as w2
    from data
    group by v
)
select 
    x.v as ego,y.v as v,nx.w2 as x2, ny.w2 as y2,
    sum(x.w_td * y.w_td) as innerproduct,
    sum(x.w_td * y.w_td) / sqrt(nx.w2 * ny.w2) as cosinesimilarity
from data as x
join data as y
    on (x.base=y.base)
join norms as nx
    on (nx.v=x.v)
join norms as ny
    on (ny.v=y.v)
where x.v < y.v
group by 1,2,3,4
order by 6 desc
```

yields

```
ego|v   |x2  |y2  |innerproduct|cosinesimilarity
--------------------------------------------------
99 |1234|41.0|38.0|23.0        |0.5826987807288609
```