# Load sqlite3 extension in python3 sqlite

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

How does one correctly load a sqlite extension into python sqlite import?

os: Windows 7 64bit
sqlite3 version: 3.14.1 64bit
python3 version: 3.5.2 64bit

Here is my process so far:
compile extension-functions.c to libsqlitefunctions.dll using this command:

```
gcc -shared -I "C:\Software\sqlite3\sqlite-master" -o libsqlitefunctions.dll extension-functions.c
```

Then I can happily use these functions in sqlite3 command line using this command:

```
SELECT load_extension('libsqlitefunctions.dll');
```

However when trying in the python script:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
con = lite.connect(db_file)
con.enable_load_extension(True)
con.load_extension("<<path to file>>\\libsqlitefunctions.dll")
```

This error appears:

> Error The specified module could not be found. :

The extension-functions.c file does include the COMPILE_SQLITE_EXTENSIONS_AS_LOADABLE_MODULE section, and in fact it loads fine when using command line sqlite3

**Additional notes:**
The python sqlite package is installed and working correctly.
I've also tried updating the sqlite3.dll in the python path to the latest version

Comment: Check if you have `sqlite3` package installed . Else use `pip install sqlite3` in your windows command prompt to install it ,and try running the code again.

Comment: @Arihant yes it is installed. All other commands work, just an issue loading the extension.

Comment: What's the complete `<<path to file>>`?

Comment: @Shawn - many different paths. I've tried every possiblity, including having the dll in the python3 PATH and the sqlite3 PATH and only putting the dll name in the call. But, by example, I would used something like this: "C:\\temp\\libsqlitefunctions.dll"

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a nice answer, but it provides a method to use the extension in python.

Output sql commands to a file, then use subprocess to run the file directly into the command line, like so:

```
import subprocess
import uuid
import os

db_file = "trial02.db"
sqlite_functions_file = "libsqlitefunctions.dll"

sql_file = uuid.uuid4() + ".sql"
with open(sql_file, 'w') as fsql:
    fsql.write('/* auto script */\n\n')
    #load extension
    sql = "SELECT load_extension('" + sqlite_functions_file + "');"
    fsql.write(sql + '\n')
    #sql scripts
    sql = "insert into t(c) values (log(2));"
    fsql.write(sql + '\n')

args = [
    'sqlite3'
    , db_file
    , '< ', sql_file
]
print(' '.join(args))
out1 = subprocess.run(' '.join(args), shell=True)
os.remove(sql_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Place `libsqlitefunctions.dll` in a folder that is visible globally like `c:\WINDOWS\` or some other folder from the `PATH` environment variable. 
Then you will be able to load the extension using simple command:

```
con.load_extension("libsqlitefunctions.dll")
```

Comment: I unpacked [sqlite3 source](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) to the same directory as [extension-functions.c](https://www.sqlite.org/contrib/download/extension-functions.c?get=25) and used this command: `gcc -fPIC -lm -shared extension-functions.c -o libsqlitefunctions.dll` to compile it, by the way. GCC came from [tdm-gcc](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) package.